# How to reverse_lazy user in template view's get_context_data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Does anyone know how I can redirect the user to another link using the `get_context_data`? The reverse lazy below is not working:

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Name, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    return reverse_lazy('link_name', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve a redirect, you should use the redirect function from django.shortcuts. Here's how you can modify your code to perform the redirect correctly:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class YourDetailView(DetailView):
    # Your view attributes and methods

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_student:
            if self.request.user.id != self.kwargs['pk']:
                return redirect('link_name', pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Your context preparation logic here
        return context
```

Comment: Can I not use it in get context data? Also, I want to use reverse lazy if possible

Comment: Also, this seems ai generated. I ran an ai detector on this answer. Please don't post such content.